# encrypt rsa android from public key .pem format

Tags: android, encryption, rsa

i already wandered in many stackoverflows post but still cant figured out whats wrong with my code.

```
public class KripAsim {
String hasil;

public String encrypt(String text) {
    try {

        String PUBLIC_KEY="MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAvCNqSslgCndo8vfNrkXFDLXmst024Oi8D7LEiJFjYBva4kBKKISe8rKp58kCLLHjv90RN+Dy2KWcf0eFkKaqc3zILBI99JhV1z8TFOzmt5dfgW6fD1ucBfsK6pWxK84DddyOqKldwHlReqjuDHT2jLue51vpXaCa12WV5bMnGsfy3vZKnp699YCguqRpTR1MijZ9pz8WqldrR0a/DCaq5YxZ7lvjwuWIodQy3S3XRHAaeaUrFHFFLumzXAGuP447oRYR0p+1qsy8+wOtrsGm8m8bMg+C1XGMblkODtOFHz3wtrRZ5OwzgEm7J7odmSX8mSYBZYLcnUVqIFRsQkZLiwIDAQAB";

        byte [] decoded = Base64.decode(PUBLIC_KEY,Base64.NO_WRAP);
        KeyFactory keyFac = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(decoded);

        PublicKey pubkey = keyFac.generatePublic(keySpec);

        Cipher rsa;
        rsa = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        rsa.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubkey);
        hasil = Base64.encodeToString(rsa.doFinal(text.getBytes("UTF-8")),Base64.NO_WRAP);
        return hasil;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return hasil;

}
}
```

it returns null. please help. thanks in advance

Comment: i got the key from .pem format and delete BEGIN and END, thats it.

Comment: Is it printing any stack traces?

Answer (score 0):

The line `PublicKey pubkey = keyFac.generatePublic(keySpec);` throws an InvalidKeySpecException because you have incorrectly supplied a [`PKCS8EncodedKeySpec`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/spec/PKCS8EncodedKeySpec.html) when you should have supplied an [`X509EncodedKeySpec`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/spec/X509EncodedKeySpec.html).

You should also completely specify the transformation string in the [`Cipher.getInstance()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) method. The following fragment taken from your code illustrates this:

```
byte[] decoded = Base64.decode(PUBLIC_KEY, Base64.DEFAULT);
X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(decoded);

PublicKey pubkey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(keySpec);
Cipher rsa = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPwithSHA-256andMGF1Padding");
rsa.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubkey);
String hasil = Base64.encodeToString(rsa.doFinal(text.getBytes("UTF-8")),
                                     Base64.NO_WRAP);
return hasil;
```

Finally, you should avoid encrypting data directly with RSA. The correct method is to use a [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) scheme in which the data is encrypted with a block cipher, say AES in GCM mode, using a randomly generated AES key, and then this key is encrypted using RSA. There are many examples of this around for reference.

Comment: im using php too, so the encrypted key will be send to server and then decrypted there. do you have any suggeestion for the padding? i use open ssl in php

Comment: @rebellatrix: That's another question for another time.